# Can an answer which was deleted due to presence of plagiarized parts from Mozilla & several SO answers be undeleted if plagiarized parts are removed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I am pretty much new to Stack Overflow. But I am going through a different experience all together. The day I started learning I created my account here. Then there had been some outstanding answers to my questions from the Stack Overflow volunteers and a few more suggestions for improvement in the answers I provided. Hence I learnt and consider a couple of Stack Overflow volunteers as my mentors and started following them.

My question:

> Can an answer, which was once deleted due to presence of plagiarized parts from developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs and several other user questions/answers, be undeleted if all the plagiarized parts are completely removed in iterations?

Sequence of events:

1. I constructed an answer after going through `developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs` and different Stack Overflow questions/answers thread which is the best place to learn.
2. My answer got a bounty.
3. Next my answer got deleted by a moderator referring to `developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs`.
4. I had a word with the same moderator and asked for help on how I can get my answer undeleted.
5. I edited my answer to remove the verbatim from `developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs` and raised a flag for moderator attention.
6. I got feedback, `Changing a few words around and tacking a link on the end isn't proper attribution.` (I knew, there were some phrases from one of my mentors, not only on Stack Overflow, but in some other developer's forum)
7. So, now I removed all of the plagiarized part from my answer and majorly focused on the usecases related to that question which no one have researched still now and submitted a flag for moderator attention.
8. I waited for some time, spoke to other moderators who confirmed me that the answer doesn't contain any plagiarized part any more.
9. But yesterday my answer was undeleted and then again deleted as earlier it contained *plagiarized parts from multiple people's words*.

What can I do to showcase my research efforts with the use cases related to that question?

Link to the answer: *[Difference between webdriver.firefox.marionette & webdriver.gecko.driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver/43920453#43920453)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this gets interesting... [another site has the *exact same examples*](http://www.fluentwait.com/?p=79), but its creation date is the 25th of May, whereas your answer was on the 11th.  I'm not noting any link between that site's creator and you, so perhaps *you* may have been plagiarized in that example.

...and my suspicion only grows ***stronger*** given that that site's content is [***verbatim*** what your first revision was](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43920453/1).

I have absolutely no insight into what the moderators were thinking, and perhaps their tools are more powerful than me simply Googling a few phrases and seeing what came up...but I wonder if they acted on that post as evidence of plagiarism?  My first instinct was, when I saw that content, to automatically presume that you copied it from somewhere, but I think that the opposite might be true.

I don't disagree with the need for attribution on key parts of the documentation, and it does seem like [you may have borrowed a bit from this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38917100/1079354), but so long as you provide the appropriate attribution, I'm really not seeing much in the way of you plagiarizing something.

Comment: Yea, that's plagiarized from multiple sources, with the words changed a little here and there. I don't really see how you'd salvage it without removing 90% of the answer's contents.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  What other sources were there again?  The link to the external site had its resources available two weeks *after* the OP's answer was posted.

Comment: The other source was Jim Evans's answer. And yes, "so long as you provide the appropriate attribution", but it was not provided. I was the first person to introduce that link into the discussion, after I went checking to see if there was still any plagiarized content in the answer. I found that there was. I'm not sure what external site you're talking about; I didn't mention any external site in my comment. (Although there very likely are portions of the answer plagiarized from other sources, too. I just didn't look that hard after finding one.)

Answer (score 23):

Plagiarism is broader than simply copy-and-paste. In other words, you can plagiarize someone else's work even if you reword everything. As explained in [Plagiarism.org's article, "What is Plagiarism?"](http://www.plagiarism.org/article/what-is-plagiarism):

> All of the following are considered plagiarism:
>
> - turning in someone else's work as your own
> - copying words or ideas from someone else without giving credit
> - failing to put a quotation in quotation marks
> - giving incorrect information about the source of a quotation
> - changing words but copying the sentence structure of a source without giving credit
> - copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not (see our section on "fair use" rules)

Most people know—or quickly understand—the first few bullet points as plagiarism, but the last two bullet points aren't always so obvious.

I've seen this confuse school-age students, too. They understand that they are not to copy text directly from other sources and that they need to put things into their own words, so they sit down and rephrase each individual sentence out of a reference book. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. It still counts as plagiarism. You didn't copy the wording, but you copied the ideas and the organization, which is where the *real* value lives anyway.

TurnItIn.com, a plagiarism detection tool commonly used in academia, defines a "plagiarism spectrum", noting 10 different common ways that students tend to plagiarize. A detailed infographic can be found [here](http://www.turnitin.com/assets/en_us/media/plagiarism_spectrum.php?_ga=2.8986037.168350716.1505121590-1706144310.1505121590), and the full study is also [available for download](http://go.turnitin.com/paper/plagiarism-spectrum). But I'll just highlight the most important parts with [a summary handout](http://storage.pardot.com/45292/46686/plagiarism_spectrum_thumbnail_2015.png):

[image]

Notice that "Clone" and "Ctrl+C" are among the most common types of plagiarism. They are also the easiest to detect, and the most obvious types of infractions, akin to the first few bullet points on the above list.

There are other forms, though, including "Remix", "Mashup", "Re-tweet", and "Hybrid". I've seen all of these on Stack Overflow and in students' papers. "Re-tweet" is essentially TurnItIn.com's clever name for what I described above: making superficial changes at the word or phrase level, without deviating significantly from the original structure and ideas.

There's a trick for avoiding this that I've suggested to students: read the original source so that you understand it, then close it and write your own paper/answer *without looking back at the original source*. This will force you to present things entirely in your own words, in your own way, based on your own understanding. In other words, this effectively ensures that you are not plagiarizing because you are writing entirely from memory. It works even better when your research draws upon multiple sources, because then you can combine them in novel ways.

Except for one thing—you *still* need to explicitly reference the original source(s) from whence you got your ideas. You may not be quoting the author directly, but they obviously still *inspired* you, and you built on top of their work, so you need to give them credit. As always, [attribution is required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

Going back to TurnItIn.com's categories, a "Remix" and "Recycle" are okay, so long as you provide a proper citation (attribution). At least, they are in the context of Stack Overflow. They probably wouldn't be okay in a strictly academic setting, but we're okay with them. Even the "Aggregator", while somewhat problematic, is acceptable on Stack Overflow under certain circumstances, especially when most of your other answers are original work.

---

Now that you understand the general problem, let's turn to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver/43920453#43920453) in particular. As you said, it went through multiple cycles of revision and flagging. It was originally flagged by another user as being plagiarized from an external source without attribution, and in response to that flag, a moderator deleted it. We have a very strict no-tolerance approach when it comes to copying content from other sources and failing to provide attribution. Posts that fail to comply with our [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) are mercilessly deleted.

You then edited the answer, claiming that you were previously told not to post link-only answers, so you copied the text. Well, that was true—you aren't supposed to post link-only answers—but what you're actually supposed to do is include the link for reference, provide proper attribution (the name of the original author and the source), and then quote or summarize the relevant portions. This is all described in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Copying and pasting large chunks of content without properly formatting it as a quotation *or* giving explicit attribution is unacceptable. Your fix for this didn't really make it any better, since you were still copying-and-pasting content, still not formatting it as a quotation, and still not providing proper attribution by our standards.

On the next attempt to improve your answer, you changed a few words around so that you were no longer copying-and-pasting, but as the discussion above should have revealed, this is still considered plagiarism. A flag to have the answer reinstated was declined by a moderator, because:

> Changing a few words around and tacking a link on the end isn't proper attribution. You are still attempting to take credit for the work of others.

On the third attempt, you apparently took that advice to heart and attempted to more comprehensively rephrase that section of your answer into your own words. You then flagged again for moderator attention, and asked that your answer be undeleted. That is where I got involved, because I'm the moderator who processed that flag. I had two problems with what you did:

1. First and most importantly, you had *removed the attribution*, which is totally unacceptable. As stated above, even if you don't copy the wording from another source, you are still using their ideas, so you still need to give them credit. Removing the attribution had made the problem *worse*, rather than better.

   I tried to give you the benefit of the doubt on this, though, and chalk it up to confusion. So I edited the attribution *back* into the answer, and undeleted it, which marked your flag as "helpful". I wouldn't have done this in an academic context, but it seemed at first glance like you had mostly solved the problems with the original answer in a way that would be acceptable on Stack Overflow.
2. Except…when I looked a bit closer, I started to doubt that you actually had fixed the problems. I checked a few key phrases from other parts of the answer and became concerned that it wasn't just *one* source that you had originally plagiarized, but *multiple* sources—and you hadn't given credit to *any* of them.

   This is the comment that I left underneath your answer, explaining why I had undeleted and then deleted it again:

   > Uhh, I had undeleted this under the impression that you had only plagiarized *one* source, and that you had tried to rectify that. However, a little investigation suggests that you have, in fact, copied *multiple people's words* to generate this answer. For example, several sentences are an exact match to [JimEvans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38917100), which was >6 months old when you composed/posted this. I'm just not comfortable letting something that may still have plagiarized content be live on the site. You can't just copy other people's efforts and get credit for them.

   I still stand by that, and based on the above discussion about the nature of plagiarism, you should better understand where I'm coming from.

   Honestly, I had neither the time, patience, nor interest in painstakingly going through your answer and verifying that none of it was plagiarized and/or that it followed our referencing guidelines. That isn't a moderator's job, and my cursory investigation suggested that it *did not* meet our guidelines, so I refused to take your flag on faith. It still seemed to me like you were trying to ["pull a fast one"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+a+fast+one), so I wasn't comfortable with undeleting the post.

   If I'm going to "sign off" on the answer (which is what I would effectively be doing by undeleting something that had previously been deleted for plagiarism), then I need to be absolutely confident that the problems have been fixed and that it meets our standards. I wasn't, and still am not.

As [Cerbrus said in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356367/can-a-answer-which-was-deleted-due-to-presence-of-plagiarized-parts-from-mozilla#comment512892_356368):

> Yea, that's plagiarized from multiple sources, with the words changed a little here and there. I don't really see how you'd salvage it without removing 90% of the answer's contents.

If you're still interested in pursing this and want to have your answer republished, then you should follow the advice above and rewrite it *completely* in your own words, without referencing any of the original materials or even the current draft of the answer. Then, make sure that you add in attribution to *all* of the resources that you consulted when writing the original answer and along the way.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Do you mean you want Cody to rewrite your answer for you? This is something you should be doing yourself, since it's your answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB You *have* gotten lots of valuable guidance.  This meta answer is *full* of it.