# Why was my NAA-flag declined? What should I do with "answers" that does not even touch on the question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I know that [Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/681538) but what about posts that clearly does not attempt to answer the actual question and instead seem to answer a completely other question that was never asked?

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269538/681538) as it doesn't contains anything that could be interpreted to even touch on an answer to the actual question but that was declined. It was instead deleted for other unrelated reasons.

What should I do with "answers" that do not address the actual question?

Comment: That's plagiarism, and plagiarism warrants a mod flag, not an NAA flag.

Comment: @Zoe But... Since when can we not link to blog posts and other resources as long as we attribute and link to the source?

Comment: linking to the source isn't enough, you need to write an answer using your own words and use external ressouces as reference or to add more details not only copy/past content from external ressource without any effort from your side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @TemaniAfif I would see that as NAA in that case?

Comment: @TemaniAfif From the site you just linked to "Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own" That does not apply here, right? He clearly linked to the source.

Comment: yes and no, it's not a trivial task to notice the copy-paste, you need to open the link and find the copied portion .. a lot of work for moderator inside *all* the amount of flag. You did this job so you use a special custom flag for this

Comment: read at the bottom *Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own*

Comment: Ok, whether this post should be regarded as plagiarism or not is not my main interest here. That is how to interpret NAA. Let's say that he made up that code himself. He would still not be trying to answer the actual question, nothing in the answer relates to the clearly defined question. Is it wrong to NAA-flag it in those cases?

Comment: NAA is for "does not answer any question plausibly on-topic for SO", it is not for answers that happen not to answer the particular question. Feel free to search more for posts on the topic and if you disagree - post a feature-request to change that policy. Note that search does surprisingly work here for such a basic use case - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=naa+declined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) The rest of what you started to quote in your question: *"Do not use the "not an answer" flag __for wrong answers__. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
__You can downvote__ such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, __but they are still answers__, so you __should not flag them__."* I don't see how that doesn't answer your question...

Comment: @Tomerikoo As I see it, for an answer to be "wrong" it has to properly address the actual question. The answer "Blue" to "How much do a blue whale weight?" is not wrong, it's not an answer to the question. It does not compile. It's like if you ask a politician "What is the best way to handle unemployment?" and you get "I will be the best President ever." back. It's not an answer to the question.

Comment: In my eyes, it is an answer. A very very bad answer and I would probably not vote for that bloke ;)

Comment: I could obviously be biased but I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of the other one I myself linked to. That question does not clarify the situation when an "answer" do not actually address the actual question.

Comment: For future readers, the question that this first got closed as a duplicate of does not address the issue at all. However [the other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined) is a good match where this issue of non-answers are discussed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> [W]hat about posts that clearly does not attempt to answer the actual question and instead seem to answer a completely other question that was never asked?

Unfortunately, opinions vary.

When handling not-an-answer (NAA) flags, some moderators read the flagged answer without ever looking at the question. For these moderators, the flagged answer had better be *obviously* not even an attempt to answer the question. It's going to have to be something like, "I have the same question", "Thanks, this worked for me", or nonsense.

Other moderators (/raises hand) *do* evaluate NAA flags in the context of the question and will therefore delete answers that are obviously irrelevant to the question that was asked. For example, a NAA flag will get me to delete a C++ answer to a Python question. However, even for me, this has its limits. I cannot be a subject matter expert on all topics covered on Stack Overflow, so there are times when what might be obviously unrelated to someone familiar with the language/technology might *look* deceptively related to me, who knows nothing about it. In these cases, I (and others) may decline NAA flags on the basis that the answer looked like an attempt to answer the question.

> I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269538) as it doesn't contains anything that could be interpreted to even touch on an answer to the actual question…

Ahh…not exactly. This is a good example of a bad example. That is indeed C# code, and it does seem to be at least tangentially related to the subject of the question, which is the buffer size for the `StreamWriter` class. A moderator who isn't an expert could easily read that as an answer providing an alternative approach, working around some default buffer limit in the .NET Framework's built-in `StreamWriter` class. That would be a valid answer to the question, and it's not something that a moderator should be deleting.

> … it was declined but instead deleted because the answer was copy-paste from a site with link.

Your NAA flag was declined because the moderator who reviewed the answer did think it was a valid attempt to answer the question. However, that moderator then noticed that the answer was copy-pasted from the linked page, without sufficient [attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). That is an *independent* reason to delete the answer, completely unrelated to your NAA flag.

If you want to bring plagiarism (lack of attribution) to moderator attention, then you need to raise a custom moderator flag (the option that gives you a textbox to type into), rather than a NAA flag. NAA flags don't indicate to moderators that we should look for plagiarism or other types of issues. They *only* indicate that we should delete the post because it isn't an attempt to answer the question.

> But if this actually was an "answer", wouldn't it be perfectly fine to copy-paste example code from somewhere else and then add a link to the source?

No. It is only fine to do this if you provide [proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). That answer didn't. See also: [more than you ever wanted to know about plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356384).

> I didn't comment on the flag since the answer already had an older explicit comment about that, but I'm now thinking that might have been a bad choice. Or had that mattered anyway?

NAA flags don't let you include any commentary. You'd need to raise a custom moderator flag if you'd wanted to include any sort of additional commentary for the moderators along with your flag. This is a good approach if you're trying to bring anything non-obvious to our attention.

But you reference a comment that the answer in question already had. That comment was this:

> What is this? This doesn't answer the question "what is the default buffer size", nor do you explain what the point of your code is.

Those are *technical* objections. Those are *not* reasons to raise a NAA flag. Moderators do not judge the technical accuracy or correctness of answers. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268409) for what happens if you ask them to try. If you believe an answer is unclear, wrong, or not useful, then the correct course of action is to downvote it.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, then I understand what I should do when I trip over these kinds of "answers". I thought I had [an orange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553) but I guess it rather was an apple made of plastic.

Comment: In the past, I recommended that folks used a custom moderator flag for borderline cases, on the theory that better communication is better.  Nowadays that practice seems to be discouraged in favor of "standard flags."  More than once I've cast a custom moderator flag recently, only to be told to "familiarize myself with the standard flags, and use those."  It doesn't seem like an improvement.

Comment: That said, thanks for clearly articulating some of the problems with the way the community interprets NAA.  Despite my best efforts, I've never been able to convince the community that these are real issues.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It seems that there is a trade-off to be made. If custom flags are encouraged, users might overuse them when standard flags would have been appropriate. Discouraging custom flags means that corner cases that should have been custom flagged, are not. As a relatively new member, I'm guessing here, but perhaps moderators over time have decided to favor the second approach as a result of being less time consuming for them.

Comment: @Alex Oranges are apples too. They're just the wrong apples.

Comment: @Scratte Well, that orange is clearly labeled "Not an answer" so I'm not sure what oranges actually are...

Comment: Oranges are citrus fruits. That analogy is stupid. Wrong answers are not the intended domain of "not an answer" flags.