# What to do when a complicated question is answered with `print("Hello World")`?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, specific-answer

The question was ["Handling two incoming data streams and combining them in python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911130/handling-two-incoming-data-streams-and-combining-them-in-python).

And the answer at the time of positing is:

> print("hello world ") i guess that might help

This was posted by a new user, and I found this in the *First Posts* queue.

Other than downvoting, what should be done in cases like this, where the answer doesn't even try to answer the question?

I don't know if it fits the criteria of "*Not an answer*":

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
> question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
> or deleted altogether.

And "*Rude or abusive*" sounds good, but the actual criteria of "*A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.*" and the link to the Stack Overflow docs makes me think this isn't the right flag.

What should be done in cases like this?

---

As the answer is now deleted, I've posted a screenshot down below:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Downvote, move on. If you have the privilege, delete vote the answer. Most you can do.

Comment: It looks like `hari` (the person who posted the answer - according to the screen capture in your question) does not have enough reputation in order to post a comment, so like many other low reputation users, [s]he posted a comment as an answer. I would suggest flagging the answer as _not an answer_ (NAA)

Comment: @Abra no. Most mods will decline flags like that. Just because an answer could be a comment doesn't mean it's NAA.

Comment: By saying `print("hello world ")`, it's obviously someone trying to be funny when it's on a complicated question. I don't think that would pass as a comment either.

Comment: @Abra doesn't look like a comment to me. Not a remotely useful one, at the very least. I'm not sure joke comments (assuming good intent but it could be outright mocking) are worth flagging. You may have a point with not an answer but not on the basis of "being a comment" but literally "not being an answer". Usually NAA is to be avoided but it feels quite appropriate here.

Comment: given that question shows bounty, this could be attempt to game the system somehow. For example, by getting auto-award with pair of fraudulent upvotes. Or simply hoping that increased exposure of bountied question will bring an undeserved upvote from a random passer by

Comment: Deleted that post, seems low-key trolling to me. I'm not sure if other mods would welcome a NAA flag on that, but I definitely would.

Comment: Personally, I'd even tend to go rude/abusive, since this seems like mocking/trolling to me and should be addressed as such in my opinion. The person posting that answer is fully aware the answer is not even remotely useful to anyone.

Comment: It is *"[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)"* (comma and exclamation point)

Comment: @PeterMortensen That alone, justifies a downvote!

Comment: So yeah, post about such answers on meta so that a willing diamond moderator will see it and delete it for you. The NAA flag *really really really* needs to work 100% of time time for answers such as this, it's just a ridiculously poor state of affairs that this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: I don't really understand the debate as to whether this is NAA (and should be flagged as such) or not? It is so clearly NAA to the given question and should be "...deleted altogether".

Comment: @MrWhite See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403121/why-was-my-naa-flag-declined-what-should-i-do-with-answers-that-does-not-even#comment810617_403121 Very related to that. Although this specific case is much more border-line... In general *not an answer __to this question__* is not a good-enough reason for *not an answer*

Comment: Maybe VLQ flag would fit?

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate answers this question perfectly. And yes, the answer on this question is patently wrong. Also, see Shog answer for what SE needs to do to address this situation.

Comment: @MrWhite: It is my understanding that the GUI presented to moderators for handling of the NAA flag does not include the question, only the answer. So, in general, a moderator can only accept the flag if the answer *cannot possibly be an answer to any imaginable question*. In other words, if you can *imagine* a question to which `print("Hello, World!")` is an answer, then it is not NAA. That's how it was explained to me, at least.

Comment: There are some people in one tag that I follow that I somewhat regularly interact with, and if one of those people (but only one of those) were to ask a complex question, I *might*, **MIGHT** be inclined to leave a *comment* like "Have you tried turning it off an on again?" But that is a very specific situation. I like *truly funny* comments, like this one: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56212796#56212796 (which has since been migrated to chat). I think comments like that are acceptable. The one in the Q, even as a comment, is not.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, it would seem, thanks. In that case, it looks like a fault in the wording for the NAA flag, that results in so many NAA flags being declined (as stated in [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286366/369434)) and having to dive into meta to realise the true meaning, since the description explicitly states: "it does not attempt to answer **the question**". The linked question does _attempt_ to resolve this (although that was 5 years ago and no change has yet been made AFAIK).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just downvote (and delete-vote if you have the rep) and move on.

It's a "funny" answer that doesn't answer the question. Don't waste your time with it other than that...