# Why was my flag declined when the answer was another computer language?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

My flag on this answer [Output looks good but code is somehow wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587951/output-looks-good-but-code-is-somehow)
First, I flagged VLQ , but it was

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

then, I flagged NAA, but it was declined with the same reason above.
Why my flag was declined while it is not in python?(It's C++ I assume) My flag long ago, I flagged something with another computer language(Python to c or something) but it was marked as `helpful`. But why not this?

So, why was my flag declined, and what action I have to take when I see these posts?

By the way, https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27780067 and my comment [Output looks good but code is somehow wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587951/output-looks-good-but-code-is-somehow-wrong/65164232#comment115204171_65164232) And I downvoted too.

Comment: Flagging these as NAA can be hit-or-miss. [Some mods will notice the lack of agreement in the language, while other mods won't.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403133) It's best to raise a custom flag explaining the problem and noting the utter irrelevance of the language in the answer to the topic of the question. I've removed the answer now.

Comment: Can anyone edit the dupe list containing this too? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403121/why-was-my-naa-flag-declined-what-should-i-do-with-answers-that-does-not-even/403133#403133

Comment: Done. Despite the possible conflict-of-interest in my having answered that question. :-)