# Why has this plagiarism flag been declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, plagiarism

I have flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803764/11878963) to contain plagiarism content from [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803718/11878963). Now I am curious to know, why the flag has been declined by a moderator ("found no evidence to support it").

#### Post history

Note: For brevity, my answer is named A, the other one B:

- I posted A before creation of B (2020-01-18 18:40:36Z vs 2020-01-18 18:47:46Z).
- [First revision of B](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59803764/1) proposed a different solution than A (perfectly fine).
- 2020-01-18 18:48:38Z, creator of B even [asked me for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript/59803764#comment105747789_59803718). I [gave further explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript/59803764#comment105747821_59803718) (2020-01-18 18:51:16Z) and edited the answer accordingly (2020-01-18 18:52:08Z).
- 2020-01-18 18:59:47Z, creator of B [edited his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59803764/2), integrated my solution and used nearly the same code example, while [not giving any credit to me](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). I guess, there is no need to go into technical details - it is sufficient to say, the *minor* changes really don't contribute any new content.

#### Research on plagiarism

According to Plagiarism.org mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356367/can-an-answer-which-was-deleted-due-to-presence-of-plagiarized-parts-from-mozill/356384#356384), plagiarism is (among others):

> - turning in someone else's work as your own
> - copying words or ideas from someone else without giving credit

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism):

> Plagiarism is the representation of another author's language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions as one's own original work.

I am also aware, that sometimes [aggregating other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17693) may be useful - but only, if  attribution is given to original authors and the post is reasonably large to justify an aggregation. Both aspects don't apply in this case.

#### Question

I actually thought, that I have a good sense of what plagiarism is. Together with the research done, I am even more surprised that the flag has been declined. Is this acceptable or tolerated behavior on Stack Overflow (if yes, why, given linked articles)?

Note: [The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript) is a bit older, I know - an upvote caught my attention again.

#### Update: flag message

> User Medet Tleukabiluly copied my answer (in same Stack Overflow post; stackoverflow.com/a/59803718/11878963) by integrating my ideas into his answer, using even the same code example, and not giving any credit to me. See timestamps of the post revisions. I know, the post is a bit older. But it still bothers me, after an upvote caught my attention again. After having read Stack Overflow help concerning plagiarism, I am now aware, that this behavior can be flagged. – bela53 5 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Comment: How else is the author of answer B supposed to explain function overloading?

Comment: Because it's not plagiarism. It's not unusual for two developers to come up with very similar code for the same problem. The post you flagged uses different variable names, includes comments on multiple lines of the code, and has an additional entirely different code block. It's clearly a very different answer. In addition, they were posted only 7 minutes apart.

Comment: @SecurityHound The person either could have kept their own distinct solution, so multiple atomic answers compose a collaborative solution of the community, separately votable. In my personal opinion, this is beneficial for small answer like this one, as no repetition is done. Or the person gives credit to authors of previous answers, when aggregating.

Comment: @KenWhite the person even asked for clarification annotated as a comment to my answer, before he integrated this solution in his answer several minutes later. There is no way, the edit is not some sort of reaction to my answer. Note: I already posted a similar comment, but apparently all comments have been cleared by a mod. Concerning different answers: The first part of his answer (first revision) certainly is the unique alternative. My concerns are about the second part added in a later revision as reaction to my answer, which is exactly the same solution.

Comment: I personally would consider this plagiarism based solely on investigating the contents of your flag. However, you haven't mentioned that there are deleted comments that would help in identifying the plagiarism (mods can see deleted comments as well). In the future, it wouldn't hurt to be explicit in the flag message about everything you think the mod should look at to make a decision.

Comment: @cigien that mention of deleted comments was in relation to *this meta question*, not the plagiarism post, we are discussing.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I thought you meant there were additional deleted comments on the main post regarding this.

Comment: Nope, but good you brought this up!

Comment: fwiw, I've looked at the posts again, and I've changed my mind about the first part of my comment. I don't think there's sufficient evidence to back up the claim of plagiarism.

Comment: This seems blown out of proportion to me. Calling this plagiarism is a stretch: your code was rewritten in an improved way (at least the author claims so) rather than copied verbatim, and it wasn't very complicated to begin with. If this happened to me, I'd probably just move on (maybe downvote, if I were in a bad mood). I definitely wouldn't bring it up 10 months after it happened.

Comment: "...the minor changes really don't contribute any new content." I guess this is the crucial part here. Often, minor changes (sometimes even a single character change) can change the nature of content tremendously, especially in programming.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Even if code is rewritten, plagiarism etiquette and the attribution rules of the content license might require giving attribution, even 10 months later (time doesn't matter). I guess the asker here wants to know why the flag was declined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is about general SO guidelines/etiquette concerning plagiarism and flagging behavior, not just me or the mentioned post. If plagiarism is a too harsh term, we might also flag it as "Copy/paste answer" or "bad manner". Concerning "improved" vs copied: Does that mean everyone can do a mashup of all previous answers/ideas without giving credit and honoring the post having come up first with the idea? Say 5 answers with partial unique solutions and each one adding the other 4 ideas (with *slight* adjustment), with idea origin being obscured? (example is consciously exaggerated)

Comment: @Trilarion In general I agree completely with your statement concerning minor changes. To be clear: In this *particular* case, the changes add *nothing*  in the sense of type checking/language improvements (I mentioned function overloads [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403191/why-has-this-plagiarism-flag-been-declined/403197?noredirect=1#comment810871_403197)). I would call that a minor superficial change, like renaming a variable or adding a `console.log` statement. Does this make your adjusted code a complete new idea with no need for attribution?

Comment: I'd say [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251585/466862) applies here, specifically _"Should you attribute when you directly use someone's complete code? Yes, absolutely. When you are inspired by someone's code? It is nice, but not required. When your code bears a passing resemblance to other code because it uses the same language constructs? Nope."_

Answer (score 36):

Let's have a look at your flag:

> A user copied my answer (in same Stack Overflow post; stackoverflow.com/a/59803718/11878963) by integrating my ideas into his answer, using even the same code example, and not giving any credit to me.

I have to squint a hell of a lot to conclude that these answers are equal. Because they are not. Primarily because you're a lot more verbose in your answer. That part definitely didn't make it into the other answer.

So, we're left with the added code example in the second revision. That is not the "same" code example. Your code sample looks incomplete, theirs seems more complete, it even comes with a link to a playground (which oddly enough shows me an error in the code).

Okay, so then it is your idea. I'm not a TypeScript subject-matter expert, but I guess the function `add` has been used a couple of times, as has function overloading, before you posted it here in this answer. If you want to uphold the "your" idea argument, then at least properly give attribution to where you copied your example from so this becomes a case of second-degree plagiarism.

It is true that some code shows resemblance with your code, but there is not enough evidence at first sight that this is plagiarism, and to me, there is no plagiarism after investigating the evidence presented. The moderator correctly declined the flag.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't define an explanation of the error cause as verbosity - as a questioner I am happy to receive this information. If I wanted to be sarcastic: that made it even easier for said person to understand and integrate the answer (just kidding; I want to be  objective here). We might argue about playground or not, but that doesn't justify an extra answer in my opinion - my answer's code is complete, and you can copy paste it in the REPL, IDE or any tool. And I already gave attribute to the source of information - it is the TypeScript handbook docs mentioning function overloads.

Comment: It is not up to you if an other answer is justified.

Comment: Well, this piece of `add` code is no rocket science - I cannot reference other "canonical" sources than the TypeScript docs them selves. I still would claim, that I had the idea of function overloads as solution first. Person B first didn't seem to know about this concept, as he had proposed an alternative and later asked for clarification at my answer (although this might be a bit speculative). Hence at least I would expect some form of credit in his answer.

Comment: One note: This is not me "wanting to have just some additional rep". The discussed behavior is wholeheartedly not in accordance with my own sense of justice. Currently, I honestly could not answer anymore, what is permitted and what not concerning plagiarism on SO.

Comment: Let me ask then: How many other cases of plagiarism on SO did you flag and did those succeed?

Comment: Yes, I am lacking experience in flagging plagiarism - I judge based on the linked references in the question and some other meta posts I have read. But I cannot quite follow, what the purpose of your question is.

Comment: Based on a sample size of one (1) I wouldn't make bold/hyperbole statements like *I honestly could not answer anymore, what is permitted and what not concerning plagiarism on SO*. Plagiarism exist on SO for sure. The case you brought up isn't one of those, or at least it isn't as clear cut for neutral observers as you believe it to be. No worries, I have had plenty of plagiarism flags declined.

Comment: I don't doubt your experience. But this is implicit knowledge. As a newcomer, my main source of information are the meta stackoverflow and stackexchange posts, which I tried to research extensively before. For me, the cited statements still speak more in favor plagiarism for me.

Comment: @bela53 that is all true. Awesome that you brought it to meta so it can be discussed and our collective knowledge and judgement can improve on what plagiarism looks like for real.

Comment: Looks to me the code was copy and pasted (adding a couple things). And the idea was also copied. The timestamps are enough to make this assumption. If you stick to irrefutable evidence, then it probably won't pass. But if you talk about _enough_ circumstantial evidence, I'd have to say it's enough to say this was plagiarized. A guy didn't have an idea until he saw another one's idea. And instead of taking the time to think of their own code, it was just easier to copy and paste. And let's change a couple things so it doesn't look obvious. Motive: fastest gun in the west gets the check. IMO

Comment: *Okay, so then it is your idea* It's the idea of function overloading that matters and not the exact code or the add function.  The second edit should not  have been made by "Person B" after the exact idea was proposed by "Person A"

Comment: @PaulSamsotha maybe it is time you post that as an answer. Currently it is only me and the user that is being accused. We certainly can do with advice how we (and mods)  need to analyze this and how this could have been prevented.

Comment: @rene Who's accusing you of anything?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha so far nobody. I meant user Medet Tleukabiluy, who wrote the second answer. And the accusation of plagiarism is made by the OP of the meta question, not by you.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha If you read it as "Currently, it is only the user who is being accused and me who have posted answers." then the ambiguity is resolved.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the clarification. I _did_ read it completely wrong.

Comment: @rene one addendum to "It is not up to you if an other answer is justified.": This is not, what I said (or intended to say). I don't judge the existence of other later answers, as long as another person does not copy my own ideas without credit.

Comment: I've never used, or heard of TS, have not read the question, nor viewed the answers. Still, from the description of the potential plagiarism I'd be inclined to suspect that any coding of a function `add` to perform the intended operations will be greater than 75%, if not nearly 99%, identical with the balance being _strikingly similar_. There may be more than one way to do it, yet they all look the same to the computer.

Answer (score 26):

I'm the author of the B answer.

1. I didn't ask [for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript/59803764#comment105747789_59803718); I corrected you - that JavaScript doesn't have overloads. You wrote

   - [*The `+` operator cannot be overloaded in JS, but we can still overload functions:*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59803718/2)
   - [*I meant TS function overloads, gonna update.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802954/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-t-and-t-in-typescript/59803764#comment105747821_59803718)
2. The B answer has an explicit returning value, while the A answer doesn't include it, which makes it useless, as it's missing concept of overloading. **So it's not a complete answer**.

```
    function add(a: any, b: any) {
        return a + b;
    }

    function add(a: any, b: any): string | number {
      return a + b;
    }
```

3. Why would I copy your answer with 9k reputation? What's the benefit? I should be doing plagiarism all the time to get 9k, but have you checked my other answers to call me a plagiarist?

Overall I understand your concern, and it's a typical problem on Stack Overflow. People copy new answers to new posts from old answers. But this is not the case.

Comment: Ad 1)  The statement is fine - but it certainly would have been a bit less misleading to add "TS" at the end: "The + operator cannot be overloaded in JS, but we can still overload functions in TS". Ad 2) it doesn't matter in this case. Function overloading is all about strong types for the caller side, the callee side just is `a + b`. If I remember correctly, I intentionally left the return type out due to the simple operation. You cannot take that as a reason for re-posting. 3). I neither judge you or your other answers. This is just about the referenced post.

Comment: @adabsurdum thanks for the info. As I get from this meta question, plagiarism seems to be a serious offense potentially spanned over multiple answers and actions - this accusation has not been my intention. I still have the feeling, mentioned behaviors should not belong to the SO etiquette.

Comment: @bela53 Simply put, your answer leaves out the return type, answer B includes it.  Therefore they are different answers, therefore not plagiarism.   Who's answer is correct (if any) is irrelevant.

Comment: @chrisneilsen If that statement is taken as litmus test for plagiarism, it would mean I could copy say another answer containing 200 lines of TS code, add a single extra explicit type, which in the original post does not exist and is implicitly inferred , and would be good to go.

Comment: This is going wrong direction. Why you still trying to find a crime here I don’t get it.
I’m here to get help, and contribute to SO, if my answer helps someone I’m fine with that. If your answer helps someone I’m fine with that too. If someone copies my answer if fine with that too, as long as I’m helping community I’m fine. But your perspective is quite selfish imho.

Comment: @bela53 - How many different ways are there to implement a function like add?  Likewise, the license you agreed to when you submitted your answer is pretty clear, you might want to read it

Comment: _add a single extra explicit type, which in the original post does not exist and is implicitly inferred_ well clearly the author of the other post doesn't agree with that.

Comment: @bela53 - These add functions don’t seem that unique to me.  [here](https://www.techgeeknext.com/angular/typescript-interview-questions) or [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading)

Comment: @SecurityHound The license allows Copying only **with attribution**

Comment: @TheMaster - I searched for each line of code and found multiple results

Comment: "Why would I copy your answer with 9k reputation? What's the benefit?" I agree with the other points, but this is a rather weak point. People do sometimes stupid things even for no apparent good reason. I guess that plagiarism even occurs just because of general laziness, not because of evil intentions. It could happen to everyone.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't doubt there is already another implementation somewhere on the net (though I did not look it up for the answer). I guess, we can only judge here scoped to the Stack Overflow network.

Comment: It might also be helpful for the discussion to not focus too deeply on the exact implementation (which is trivial here) disassembling each line of code and rather question, if it is OK to copy the *idea* of someone else, who posted first. See [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403191/why-has-this-plagiarism-flag-been-declined/403197?noredirect=1#comment810928_403191) [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403191/why-has-this-plagiarism-flag-been-declined/403197?noredirect=1#comment810933_403191) for a clarification.

Comment: @bela53 - I think it actually is important.  Programming languages, specifically code for an application, doesn’t have the same protection has the written language.  The implementation of overloading the add function can only be done so many ways in TrueScript.  **If they had copied your explanation I would feel differently**

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly in summary, as much as I (really) would like to believe you: the second point makes your statement non-credible. "The B answer has an explicit returning value, while the A answer doesn't include it, which makes it useless, as it's missing concept of overloading." is a complete exaggeration, particular in this case. It makes me believe that you a) had just heard about function overloading in my answer at that time and b) want to hush up things here.

Answer (score -7):

It is quite obvious to me that the second part of the answer B had the answer A as starting point. These two lines of code are identical in both answers:

```
function add(a: string, b: string): string 
function add(a: number, b: number): number
```

The probability of the author B writing these two lines from scratch, and not copy-pasting them from the answer A, that was already visible in the distance of a scroll-up, is minuscule. For this reason I can understand author's A mild annoyance for not being referenced/credited at all by the author B. From the author's B perspective, IMHO it's not too late to give the omitted credit. This could also give them the chance to explain in what aspect their code-example constitutes an improvement over the other author's example. I think that this would be beneficial to the future readers of the question as well.

Comment: [Except it’s not unique code](https://www.techgeeknext.com/angular/typescript-interview-questions) or [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading)

Comment: @SecurityHound good find!

Comment: In languages that define overloaded functions by the types of the parameters that each overloaded variant accepts, these two forms of an `add()` function are going to be the **obvious** similarity between answers. You can’t answer the question correctly and **not** have these two lines. Unless there is some odd non-standard spacing unique to the source lines they’d be the first lines I ignore if I were to look for blatant copying.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Is it a convention to name the parameters `a` and `b` (not a rhetorical question)? (When [sorting in Perl, it often ***must*** be $a and $b](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) (global variables, though).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: the *question* uses those parameter names.