# Totally wrong feedback to review. Bug in robot review?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have reviewed an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27936576) which was absolutely relevant. But I've got a feedback that the answer was "abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable. ... Please **delete** or **recommend deletion** when reviewing such posts."

What did I do wrong here? I think the audit is bad.

Where do these audit recommendations come from?

**Update** If the reason is plagiarism, it should be named as such. If the reason is links that promote 3rd party Q/A sites, this should be named as such. If the answer is relevant, but not very useful, it should remain and users who find it not useful should be able to vote it down. I think the current audit mechanism needs to be improved.

[image]

Comment: I understand your frustration at failing this audit. However, I would suggest framing the question in a way that provides constructive suggestions, and that indicates you're looking for feedback, rather than as an attack.

Comment: Did you check the links? They are possibly misleading. And also checked this [answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10241047/11682469) which seems to have been plagiarized? One advanced spammer tactic is to plagiarize text from somewhere else to make it look like legit answer and then add their links.

Comment: @cigien: When I fail I usually understand the reasons and agree. But this is obviously a problem in the audit system. How would you formulate it?

Comment: I have made some minimal edits to your question to indicate what I mean. Please do edit it further as you see fit.

Comment: @JeanneDark: Some links are obviously relevant, some may be relevant in a specific case. In any case, they are not wrong and the answer is absolutely **relevant**.

Comment: @cigien: The answer has nothing to do with spam nor plagiarism, the links are relevant, some more, some less. The answer is **relevant**.

Comment: @mentallurg Are you sure you meant to ping me? I haven't discussed the merits of the audit at all.

Comment: Just looking at your screenshot, the bottom of that answer reads like an advertisement.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: What do you mean? The bottom are valid links to the Microsoft web site and they are really related to the MS SQL server. Where do you see an advertisement?

Comment: @Braiam: No, this has nothing to do with plagiarism.

Comment: @mentallurg Yes, it does. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881543 The answer is an undisclosed copy of another answer plus links to some commercial off-site resource.

Comment: I said it reads like an ad, not that it was. Do either of those links have any relevance to the question (other than being about SQL Server)? Just from the link text the two links don't sound related to a specific problem, and the identical end of that text sounds like it was a simple copy-and-paste to get around SO filters. If those links do have question-relevant info, some portion of it should be included in the answer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: OK, the first part of the answer is really the same. But it does not mean that the answer it wrong and should be deleted? This is nonsense.

Comment: Relevant: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: The links are related to the question. May be they are not 100% helpful. But for non-helpful but **relevant** answers there is downvoting. The answer is **relevant**.

Comment: If you have a hard to time understanding that plagiarized content should be deleted, then maybe don't do reviews anymore? No one is forcing you to do so.

Comment: @Tom: The answer is helpful. Or you don't want help developers get helpful answers?

Comment: I'm not saying the answer is wrong, I'm saying the answer is plagiarized with promotional links added. That's not "Looks okay"; stuff like that should be removed. Answers shall provide original content, and third party content must be referenced properly. Maybe this audit is too subtle, but it certainly is not incorrect. @mentallurg

Comment: @BaummitAugen: No. There are no promotional links.

Comment: I think it's a bit much to expect reviewers to google sections of an answer to see if it's plagiarized, if there aren't any other answers on the question. But the bottom section definitely seems unrelated to the question. (Related to the tag, yes; related to the question, no.) At the very least, I think a reviewer should have edited that part out.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: The answer is absolutely **relevant**. It is absolutely wrong to call it *blatantly off-topic*.

Comment: @mentallurg Even if those links somehow were not promotional, the answer is still plagiarism plus links. We don't let plagiarism stand just because it is somehow relevant plagiarism. Again, the audit might be overly subtle, but "Looks okay" is absolutely not the right outcome here.

Comment: Those are promotional links. These have nothing to do with the question. Those are random links from the Microsoft Q&A site and only selected because they tackle the same software provided by Microsoft. That's not the first user to post those "hot issues [month]" links. Also regarding your "Or you don't want help developers get helpful answers" question: if that requires me to steal someone elses content and need to combine that with spam, then no, not the action I would do.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If that's too much for someone, then they don't need to do reviews. No one forces them to do them.

Comment: @Tom: I am not sure how you understand "promotional". Promotional means advertising. MS SQL Server is well known and does not need any advertising. SO the links are definitely **not** promotional.

Comment: @Tom: To plagiarism: Is any answer to the question about NullPointerExsception not plagiarism? There are hundreds of questions about NullPointerExsception. Why all of thema are not closed as plagiarism except the very first one?

Comment: As has been mentioned multiple times, the "relevant" content of this post is plagiarized from [another answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/7881543). The bottom portion of the "answer" is *completely* promotional, as were the 80+ other answers which also had nearly identical spam. The bottom of the answer you are reviewing boils down to: "Check out my great thing! [link to something on my great site that is only semi-related] - Hot issue for November [link to another thing on my great site that is barely related] -Hot issue for November". That's **spam**.

Comment: So you don't understand what "plagiarism" means? It doesn't mean "has the same topic", it means copying someone elses work and declare it as your own. That's what that answer does. Also you don't seem to understand what those links promote. It is (rather obviously) not MS SQL itself, but the linked Q&A.

Comment: @mentallurg If you think some other post on SO is plagiarized, then please raise an "in need of moderator intervention flag" on the post. In the flag, explain the issue and provide a link to the source (or at least *a* source) which can be shown to have existed prior to the content being placed in the SO post you are flagging. That some other thing is plagiarized doesn't justify plagiarizing the content. To generalize that: That one person violates the rules does not justify another person violating the rules. Each case and user is handled individually.

Comment: @Makyen: OK, but isn't that an indicator that the question should be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @mentallurg Yes, it is an indicator that the questions might be duplicates (as, potentially, are the other questions on which that same original answer has been plagiarized into other answers). If you are a Subject Mater Expert (SME) and can judge that they are actually duplicates, then, by all means, vote to close as a duplicate. I'm not an SME in that area, so I am not making a judgement as to the questions being duplicates.

Answer (score 16):

The audit was not incorrect as such, as the answer under review consisted entirely out of plagiarism from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881543 with some promotional links to an off-site resource added. Thus, removing the post was the correct outcome, and "Looks okay" was indeed an incorrect review action.

However, as an audit, this might be overly subtle, so in line with an [earlier, similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65229411/), I removed the post under discussion from the audit pool.

Comment: Obviously the fix of this is to remove spam audits from the low quality review queue and include them in the first post and late answer review queue (late answers is perfect, because you are asked to check if this answer add something over other answers),

Comment: If the answer is a copy of some other answer, doesn't it mean the question is a duplicate of another question? Why was the question not closed as a duplicate? Latest when a "palgiarism" was detected that would be the reason to close such question as a **duplicate**.

Comment: @mentallurg I'm not  a subject matter expert, so I'm hesitant to swing my mod hammer here and just close it. But if the question is in fact a duplicate, it should absolutely be closed as such, by users who can make that call.

Comment: @mentallurg *"If the answer is a copy of some other answer, doesn't it mean the question is a duplicate of another question?"* ... it is only a duplicate when it answers the same question. When that other answer was only plagiarized to have something to add those spam links to, but it doesn't really answer the question, then it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @mentallurg no. Duplicate questions means that the question themselves are duplicates, nothing to do with the answers.

Comment: @Tom: If the answer is not related at all, this is a spam, not plagiarism. Plagiarism means that first of all it is relevant, and only then that it is a copy.

Comment: That's not what plagiarism means. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism): "Plagiarism is the representation of another author's language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions as one's own original work." It needn't be relevant to be plagiarism.

Comment: @mentallurg do you really believe someone posting spam cares? They were just trying to look legitimate to unobservant eyes. The only purpose of that answer was to promote those links. Answering the question was not.

Comment: @JeanneDark: I don't object about this particular case. But the definition in Wikipedia is way too generic and is hardly applicable. For instance, if the question is "Why NullPointerException occurs?", the millions of developers will give the same answer, without reading answers of someone other. But their same answers **are not** plagiarism.

Comment: That still wouldn't be plagiarism, @mentallurg, as those developers would have arrived at the same answer independently. They wouldn't have taken someone else's prior work and attempted to claim credit for it.

Comment: @CodyGray: They wouldn't taken someone else's work. But their answers would be the same. How would you distinguish them?

Comment: Common sense, date-time stamps, and analysis of the answers. We do this all the time. I admit it isn't perfect, but since we aren't awarding diplomas, perfection is not essential. The true, unabashed plagiarism is pretty easy to detect. @mentallurg

Comment: @CodyGray: The answer for the question about NullPointerException is so simple and short, that there is nothing to analyze. The answer is "Because variable *abc* is *null*". But it is so simple, that many developers will provide the same wording *without* knowing the answers of the others. Based on the definition in Wikipedia it would be plagiarism. But if smb. is even not aware of the answers of the others, that would be unfair to call them plagiarism. So you don't answer how can we distinguish that. I think we need better criteria for this.

Comment: Do you actually think that some answers to the NullPointerException canonical question were plagiarized? If so, have you raised a moderator flag on those answers? @mentallurg

Comment: @CodyGray: I say *vice versa*: If you ask 10 developers about NullPointerException, 8 will give *identical* answers. But calling these identical answers plagiarism would be absolutely wrong. Identical text is not sufficient to consider an answer as plagiarism. If the answer is as long as 2000 characters, I would say very probably it is plagiarism. But if the answer is 100 - 200 characters long, then identical text is to me not necessarily plagiarism. How do we want to distinguish plagiarism and *independent honest legitimate identical* (relatively short) answers?

Comment: Is there an actual problem that you're trying to solve, @mentallurg, or are you just asking hypothetically? There's no way to make a perfect determination here, and that's not just on SO. It goes for any context. In academic settings, someone has to make a judgment call about whether it counts plagiarism or not. Moderators make a similar judgment call. We probably err more on the side of leniency than the typical professor or university review board, but we are just making the same judgment call. Most of the time, I agree, programming solutions are obvious and would be arrived at independently

Comment: @CodyGray: "Jeanne Dark" above used Wikipedia as an argument for the OP. What I say is that definition in Wikipedia cannot be used as a criterion to distinguish plagiarism.

Comment: I'm well aware of different types of plagiarism. I've discussed that in [a previous answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356384). No, the Wikipedia definition is not perfect, but it is a good starting point. And I cannot find anything in Jeanne Dark's comment to disagree with. What is it that you disagree with, @mentallurg? What is the actual concern that you have? Do you not think that moderators deal properly with plagiarism?

Comment: @CodyGray: This is the first example of plagiarism. It is not sufficient to say anything about how moderators deals with that :) To "*I cannot find anything in Jeanne Dark's comment to disagree with*" - your statement above is different, you are saying it depends (date-time stamps, etc.) You disagreed with this answer in your other comment above. I'd clarified what I wanted to know: Besides "Jeanne Dark" who judges based on Wikipedia there are others like you who understand that it depends on the context. To me it's fine.